# ETH Transaction Fails but My Funds are Not Delivered Back

Tags: gas-refund

I am trying to send ETH from Ledger to CoinMetro account. I tried three times so far, with slow, medium and fast options. Each time it failed due to "out of gas" error. I did some research and my understanding is that if it fails you get the funds back with the gas fees. So far, I got the bulk of my ETH, but I did not receive the gas fees. Am I missing something? Why is there a gas fee if the transaction does not go through? Can you help me claim the gas fee? I feel like each time I try, I am loosing value.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0c3c60a41c26be4c05408e1a6d07c9d75226482f9f2f8c117d4ba9d244eb3080

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8a739d43df5bf5c1613103ce9221a61535577d67648bb203d15108d52bca4100

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x768b3046f0c99cc9355b6d5d35c57fe0e7bdfc1b20e42cc85ec332ae9273d2b9

Comment: I tried 4th time. It immediately failed, and kept the gas fee again. One interesting thing I noticed is that, Ledger Live keeps track of how much coin you have over time. On September 11 I had 1.93 ETH, now it shows that I had 1.90 ETH on September 11. I am so confused why this is happening.

Comment: gas fees arent returned ever. Its like filling a car with petrol and not reaching your destination, you still used the gas.

Comment: Basically, every time you try to do transaction. You are taking the risk of loosing your gas fee. That stinks. Thank you for reply.